# Compute the square root of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721725/how-to-solve-quadratic-function-with-degree-higher-than-two). I solved the equation $z^4 - 6z^2 + 25 = 0$ and I found four answer to be $z = \pm\sqrt{3 \pm 4i}$.

However someone in the comment said that the answer is going to be $2+i$, $2-i$, $-2+i$, $-2-i$. I cannot understand how we can find these roots from the answer that I found. How are we supposed to compute the square root of a complex number?

Comment: "I would like to know how we can approach this question using DeMoivre theorem?" This is not mentioned in the question, right?

Comment: @Did You are right. In fact I was thinking that DeMoivre theorem is the only way to solve this until Ishfaaq show me an alternative way.

Comment: Indeed, De Moivre could be the most ineffective approach here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Hint:***

Let $x  + yi = \sqrt{a  + bi}$. Then $(x+ yi)^2 = a + bi$. Then solve for $x$ and $y$ and you will generally have two sets of values for the square root $ \sqrt{a  + bi}$

Example:

Say you want to compute $\sqrt{3 + 4i}$. Then assume the square root is $a + bi$. That is $a + bi = \sqrt{3 + 4i} \implies (a + bi)^2 = (a^2 - b^2) + 2abi = 3 + 4i$. Now solve the equations $ (a^2 - b^2) = 3$ and $2ab = 4$ to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you meant $x+yi=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (modulus of a complex number)?

Comment: He is assuming there is a complex number of the form $x+yi$ whose square root is $a+bi$

Comment: It does not make sense to set $x+yi = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$ because this essentially says that the number is equal to it's magnitude. What you are doing is setting one complex number ($x+yi$) equal to the square root of another ($a+bi$)

Comment: Indeed you are right @Brad. I should have said $|x+yi| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Thank for the thorough explnation @Ishfaaq. I just did not understand one small step. $(a + b)^2 = (a + b)(a + b) = a^2+ 2ab + b^2$. Why you have written $(a + bi)^2 = (a^2-b^2) + 2abi$? Shouldn't it be $a^2 + b^2$?

Comment: We have to assume the square root too is a complex number so $(a + bi)$ is one such complex number where $i = \sqrt{-1}$. So $(a + bi)^2 = a^2 + (bi)^2 + 2abi$. Here, $(bi)^2 = b^2i^2 = b^2(\sqrt{-1})^2 = b^2(-1)$

Comment: You are absolutely right. I completly ignored the $i^2$. Is there any other way to find the roots? Can DeMoivre's Theorem or polar form used to find the roots?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure. From what I've learned De Moivre's Theorem applies for natural numbers. Not entirely sure about it. And this is the only one I know I'm afraid. If there are other methods you will get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\sqrt{3+4i}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$ for some $r,\theta$. Squaring both sides, and using de Moivre, we get $$3+4i=r^2(\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta)$$ so $$3=r^2\cos2\theta,\qquad4=r^2\sin2\theta$$ Squaring and adding gives $$25=3^2+4^2=r^4(\cos^22\theta+\sin^22\theta)=r^4$$ so $r=\sqrt5$. Dividing gives $$\tan2\theta=4/3$$ and $\theta=(1/2)\arctan(4/3)$. So, $$\sqrt{3+4i}=\sqrt5(\cos((1/2)\arctan(4/3))+i\sin((1/2)\arctan(4/3)))$$ This isn't exactly what you want, so let's have a look at that arctangent. Recall $$\tan2\theta={2\tan\theta\over1-\tan^2\theta}={2u\over1-u^2}$$ where I introduce the abbreviation $u=\tan\theta$. So, $${2u\over1-u^2}={4\over3}$$ This is $2u^2+3u-2=0$, $u=(-3\pm5)/4$. Let's take the plus sign, $u=1/2=\tan\theta$, so $\cos\theta=2/\sqrt5$, $\sin\theta=1/\sqrt5$. Now $$\sqrt{3+4i}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=\sqrt5((2/\sqrt5)+i(1/\sqrt5))=2+i$$ With a little more care, you get the other three solutions.

It would seem de Moivre is not the best way to go, here.

Comment: You should know better than using $\sqrt{\ }$ applied to a complex number.

Comment: @Did, what's wrong with $\sqrt z$? Yes, I understand that $2-i$ is on an equal footing with $2+i$; I'm happy to let OP work through the argument to see how to get both numbers.

Comment: Well, I am a bit surprised to have to elaborate on this point but, to begin with, if $\sqrt{3+4i}=2+i$ and $\sqrt{3+4i}=-2-i$ (rather than your $2-i$, I guess) then $2+i=-2-i$ hence $1=0$. Thus one needs to specify that $\sqrt{3+4i}=2+i$ and $\sqrt{3+4i}\ne-2-i$. But this arbitrary convention leads to a function $\sqrt{\ }$ which cannot be continuous on the complex plane and such that $\sqrt{zw}$ is not always $\sqrt{z}\cdot\sqrt{w}$. All in all, the insistence on applying $\sqrt{\ }$ to complex numbers seems to have disastrous effects and very few, if any, positive ones.

Comment: As an aside I fail to see what "you get the other three solutions" in your answer is referring to.

Comment: @Did, first, of course you are right that I wrote $2-i$ but meant $-2-i$. But I maintain no harm is done provided one understands $\sqrt z$ as not a number but a (rather small) set of numbers. By "the other three solutions", I meant to the quartic in the body of the question.

Comment: If $\sqrt{z}$ is not a number, I fail to understand "Let $\sqrt{3+4i}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ for some $r,\theta$."

Comment: It just takes a little interpretation; take it as, let one value of $\sqrt{3+4i}$ be $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$.

Comment: Then just don't use the notation "$\sqrt{3+4i}$". By the way, I am curious, do you know any serious textbook that uses it?

Comment: @Did, OP used it, and as I was responding to OP, I used it. Perhaps I missed an opportunity to explain to OP why one shouldn't use it, but I thought I had enough on my plate, trying to make use of de Moivre on a problem where there were better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(x+iy)^2 = a+ib$ with $a,b$ real and you want to find real values for $x$ and $y$.

Then $(x^2-y^2) + i(2xy) = a+ib$. Since $a,b,x,y$ are real, this is equivalent to $x^2-y^2 = a$ and $2xy = b$

$(x^2+y^2)^2 = (x^2-y^2)^2 + 4x^2y^2 = a^2+b^2$, so $x^2+y^2 = \sqrt {a^2+b^2}$. You always pick the positive root because $x^2+y^2$ is positive.
Then, $x^2 = \frac {\sqrt {a^2+b^2}+a}2$, so that $x = \pm \sqrt \frac {\sqrt {a^2+b^2}+a}2$, and finally $y = \frac b{2x}$ if $x \neq 0$.
If $x = 0$ you have to use $y = \pm \sqrt \frac {\sqrt {a^2+b^2}-a}2$ instead.

Here, for $a=3, b=4$, $a^2+b^2 = 9+16 = 25 = 5^2$ so that $x = \pm \sqrt {\frac{5+3}2} = \pm 2$, and $y = \frac 4 {2x} = \pm 1$ (with the same sign as $x$). This gives the two square roots of $3+4i$ .

Comment: But the request was for an approach using de Moivre.

Answer (score 1):

> *How are we supposed to compute the square root of a complex number?*

If $z$ is a nonpositive real number, the square roots are $\pm\sqrt{-z}\cdot\mathrm i$. Otherwise, the square roots of $z$ are

> $$
> \pm\sqrt{r}\cdot\frac{z+r}{|z+r|},\qquad\text{with}\ r=|z|.
> $$

The formula is legit because $z+r\ne0$. The whole procedure requires to use the usual operations $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, and to compute thrice the square root of some positive real number... but nothing else.

---

*Example:* If $z=3+4\mathrm i$ then $r^2=3^2+4^2$ hence $r=5$, $z+r=8+4\mathrm i$, that is, $z+r=4(2+\mathrm i)$, $|z+r|=4|2+\mathrm i|=4\sqrt5$ and the square roots are
$$
\pm\sqrt5\cdot\frac{4(2+\mathrm i)}{4\sqrt5}=\pm(2+\mathrm i).
$$
For a somewhat less *made up* example, consider $z=3+2\mathrm i$, then the identity above shows that the square roots of $z$ are
$$
\pm\frac{3+\sqrt{13}+2\mathrm i}{\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt{3+\sqrt{13}}}.
$$

Comment: Have you used de Moivre here, as requested?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You cannot say? I am surprised... (See comment to main answer.)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "main answer". There is one answer with many upvotes, but it also has many comments, none from you. Anyway, OP predicated the bounty on an answer using de Moivre. I agree that de Moivre is less than optimal here, but they say the customer is always right.

Comment: Sorry: *main question.