# How to find $n$ on equations that look like $x^n -n$ so it is divided by $y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

So I have this problem, $W=3^n -n -1$. How to find all $n$ so $W$ can be divided by $5$.

*what I tried:*
I found all the remainders of $3^n$ divided by $5$, they are: $1,3,4,2$.

if there isn't ($-n$), it's easy but with it I can't continue.

this is the solutions of the problem: $n=20k+11$, $n=20k+18$, $n=20k+17$, $n=20k$. but I don't know how to find them

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The remainder when $n$ is divided by $5$ depends on $n\bmod5$, and the remainder when $3^n$ is divided by $5$ depends on $n\bmod4$, so the remainder when $3^n-n-1$ is divided by $5$ depends on $n\bmod20$

Comment: thanks a lot, but I understand this [[The remainder....depends on nmod4]] but I don't understand how you went to [[so the remainder when 3n−n−1 is divided by 5 depends on nmod20]]

Comment: Check out the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: thanks a lot I understan now

Comment: Since you deleted [the post I was in the middle of commenting on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780949/how-can-you-go-from-a2b22ab-to-ab2), I'll post my comment here: See [Compute the square root of a complex number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/722852/13130), especially the accepted answer.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thanks a lot that what I was looking for, I'm sorry I didn't see the comment until today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notice that $3^4$ is congruent 1 mod 5 (by fermat's little theorem). Then, as you said, these residues are 1, 3, 4, 2, so consider next 4 cases:

1. n is congruent 0 mod 4. now, let's see it modulo 5: $1-n-1=0  (mod 5)$. That implies $n=0 (mod5)$. Using chinese residue theorem, we obtain that $n=0 (mod 20)$

Now we have found the first solution: $n=20k$.

Use the same argument in the other congruences of $n$ mod 4 to find all the other solutions.

Hope it was useful :)

Comment: thanks a lot man, I learned something today

Answer (score 0):

Let $W_n=3^n -n -1$.
Then $W_n \bmod 5$ is periodic of period $20$:
$$
0,1,1,3,1,2,2,4,2,3,3,0,3,4,4,1,4,0,0,2,0,1,1,3,\dots
$$

This follows by induction because $W_n= 3^n -n1^n -1^n$ and so $W_{n+3}=5W_{n+2}-7W_{n+1}+3W_n$ because $(x-3)(x-1)^2=x^3 - 5 x^2 + 7 x - 3$.

Comment: thanks a lot but I think this is high level math, and I'm still in highschool so... thanks anyway

Comment: @18.99, here is a starting point for this approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients